# Rails: Pass Params Through Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, parameters

I need to pass params through javascript back to the server. At the moment, I pass them into javascript like so:

```
sendParams("<%= params[:q].to_json %>");
```

And then send them back like this:

```
function sendParams(q){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/mymodel/myaction',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'q':q},
    contentType: 'json'
  });
}
```

In my controller, I try to use them like I would any other params:

```
MyModel.where(params[:q])
```

But the params are coming back empty, even though firebug shows this in the POST tab:

```
q=%7B%26quot%3Bc%26quot%3B%3A%7B%26quot%3B0%26quot%3B%3A%7B%26quot%3Ba%26quot%3B%3A%7B%26quot%3B0%26quot%3B%3A%7B%26quot%3Bname%26quot%3B%3A%26quot%3Btitle%26quot%3B%7D%7D%2C%26quot%3Bp%26quot%3B%3A%26quot%3Bcont%26quot%3B%2C%26quot%3Bv%26quot%3B%3A%7B%26quot%3B0%26quot%3B%3A%7B%26quot%3Bvalue%26quot%3B%3A%26quot%3B2%26quot%3B%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%26quot%3Bs%26quot%3B%3A%7B%26quot%3B0%26quot%3B%3A%7B%26quot%3Bname%26quot%3B%3A%26quot%3Bvotes_popularity%26quot%3B%2C%26quot%3Bdir%26quot%3B%3A%26quot%3Bdesc%26quot%3B%7D%7D%7D
```

Any idea why this information isn't getting processed by the where clause? What can I do to make the params Rails readable again?

UPDATE:

```
Started POST "/publications/search?scroll=active&page=6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-0
2-12 22:55:24 -0600
Processing by PublicationsController#index as */*
Parameters: {"scroll"=>"active", "page"=>"6"}
```

UPDATE 2:

The problem is apparently stemming from `contentType`. When I remove it, then `q` is sent as a Rails parameter. Unfortunately, `q` is still in JSON, resulting in the error:

```
undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<String:0x686d0a8>
```

How can I convert JSON to a params hash?

Comment: Can you display the request and the params logged in the development.log. I assume it is a dev env.

Comment: Good catch. "q" isn't appearing in the parameters at all. I'm assuming it should, even though it's in the post data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were a couple of issues that needed to be resolved for this to work. First, `q` wasn't being sent as a parameter to Rails, even though it was posting. The reason was because it was being treated as JSON data rather than as a parameter. I fixed this by removing the line:

```
contentType: 'json'
```

After that, the AJAX properly sent 'q', but Rails had trouble using it as it was in JSON. I had to parse it with `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode`, but this was throwing a `737: unexpected token` error. I ran the code through (JSONlint)[http://jsonlint.com/], and it turns out that all the quotation marks had been escaped.

From there, there were two solutions. The obvious one was to use `.html_safe` like so:

```
sendParams("<%= params[:q].to_json.html_safe %>");
```

But this caused problems when the user inputed quotes. The safer alternative was to decode the escaped HTML entities after they were passed back to Rails like so:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(CGI.unescapeHTML(params[:q]))
```

And this did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Your data parameter is wrong.

You have

```
data: {'q':q},
```

It should be

```
data: {q: 'q'},
```

Comment: Good point. I shouldn't be putting the first 'q' in quotes, though in my case, I think I should be leaving the second q unquoted. (It's an argument that I've passed into the function.) Unfortunately, trying both the quoted and unquoted second q still doesn't work. The q parameter for some reason isn't getting passed, according to my log.