# Dropzone on Rails causing double form submission to DB

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, paperclip, dropzone.js

When the "Save" button is clicked, there are two entries created. One with the :map information stored, and one missing it, both with same :name. How do I get only the complete entry to save?

new.html.erb

```
<%=form_for [@location, @floor], html: {class: "dropzone", multipart: true, id: "map-upload"} do |f|%>
  <div>
    <%=f.label :name%>
    <%=f.text_field :name%>
  </div>

  <div class="fallback">
    <%=f.label :map%>
    <%=f.file_field :map%>
  </div>

  <%=f.submit "Save", id: "floor-submit"%>
<%end%>
```

drag-drop.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // disable auto discover
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  var mapUpload = new Dropzone("#map-upload", {
    paramName: "floor[map]",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFiles: 1,
    addRemoveLinks: false,
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Drag & drop a map image file here, or click here to select file to upload',
  });

  $('#map-upload').submit(function(e){
    mapUpload.processQueue();
  });
});
```

Relevant part of floor_controller:

```
  def create
    @floor = current_user.company.locations.find(params[:location_id]).floors.create(floor_params)

    if @floor.save
      flash[:notice] = "Floor has been created."
      redirect_to location_floors_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "There was an error saving the floor, please try again"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

model

```
class Floor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location

  has_attached_file :map
  validates_attachment_content_type :map, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your js is submitting it once and your rails form is submitting it the second time. Would recommend disabling one of them.

Comment: I agree. If I .preventDefault() on the form submit then I'm unable to redirect back to the index. If I cancel the .processQueue() then the image won't upload. Therein lies my dilemma.

Comment: I think if you do prevent default on the form, you still still just add a redirect to index action from your js. e.g. location.href = /index after your processqueue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant a redirect to the index method of my rails controller. It requires a param from the users account, so I can't do a simple redirect through jQuery (or not that I've found).

Comment: pass the param along with your js request? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846626/rails-pass-params-through-ajax